# Minimum value for each day

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I hava a short question:
I need to take a minimum value for each day in the table like below:

```
Date                Price
2018-09-01 10:00:00 123
2018-09-01 10:01:00 2568
2018-09-01 10:02:00 2155
2018-09-01 10:03:00 23
2018-09-02 10:03:00 25868
2018-09-02 10:10:00 84213
2018-09-03 15:10:00 58192
2018-09-03 10:16:00 36
2018-09-03 10:17:00 9
```

So result should be like this:

```
Date                Price
2018-09-01 10:03:00 23
2018-09-02 10:03:00 25868
2018-09-03 10:17:00 9
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT MIN(price), data
FROM table
WHERE data BETWEEN '2018-09-01%' AND "2018-09-03%"
GROUP BY date
```

And I have an issue here. I can't write a query that will not take into account hours and seconds, only days. Could any one help me to solve this issue ?

Thanks for any answers

Comment: Use `DATE(date)` to get the date part of the datetime.

Comment: Is the name of the column `data` or `date`?

Comment: `pgadmin` is for PostGres, not MySQL. Did you mean `PhpMyAdmin`? Either way, it's not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must extract DATE from values

```
SELECT MIN(price), DATE(date) as d
FROM table
WHERE data BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND "2018-09-03"
GROUP BY d
```

Comment: @Tmiskiewicz If the answer worked for you please do accept the answer.

Comment: @Strawberry You are right. I'm sorry, I copied it from the question accidentally. I fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your `BETWEEN` clause is supposed to be.  It appears to be using `LIKE` wildcards, but without `LIKE`.

You should use simple date comparisons.  The query should look like:

```
SELECT date(data) as thedate, MIN(price), data
FROM table
WHERE data >= '2018-09-01' AND data < '2018-09-04'
GROUP BY thedate ;
```

Your attempt to use strings can cause misleading results as well as degrade performance (because it prevents use of an index).